# Preparing dataframe to carry k-means clustering

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, dbscan

Im trying to apply 3 different algorithms of clustering on my dataset.
to check which one fits the best. I'm confused how should I convert my dataframe

-k-means
-DBSCAN
-hierarchical clustering

Dataset (bank.csv)
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing
(bank.csv with 10% of the examples and 17 inputs, randomly selected from 
3 (older version of this dataset with less inputs))

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/
(direct download)

```
'data.frame':   4521 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ age      : int  30 33 35 30 59 35 36 39 41 43 ...
 $ job      : chr  "unemployed" "services" "management" "management" ...
 $ marital  : chr  "married" "married" "single" "married" ...
 $ education: chr  "primary" "secondary" "tertiary" "tertiary" ...
 $ default  : chr  "no" "no" "no" "no" ...
 $ balance  : int  1787 4789 1350 1476 0 747 307 147 221 -88 ...
 $ housing  : chr  "no" "yes" "yes" "yes" ...
 $ loan     : chr  "no" "yes" "no" "yes" ...
 $ contact  : chr  "cellular" "cellular" "cellular" "unknown" ...
 $ day      : int  19 11 16 3 5 23 14 6 14 17 ...
 $ month    : chr  "oct" "may" "apr" "jun" ...
 $ duration : int  79 220 185 199 226 141 341 151 57 313 ...
 $ campaign : int  1 1 1 4 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ pdays    : int  -1 339 330 -1 -1 176 330 -1 -1 147 ...
 $ previous : int  0 4 1 0 0 3 2 0 0 2 ...
 $ poutcome : chr  "unknown" "failure" "failure" "unknown" ...
 $ y        : chr  "no" "no" "no" "no" ...
```

I know that my data for clustering should be converted to integers. So i converted it like this (badly):

```
#Import data to R

bank <- read.table(file="bank.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# character data into numeric format
bank$job <- as.numeric(as.factor(bank$job))
bank$marital <- as.numeric(as.factor(bank$marital))
bank$education <- as.numeric(as.factor(bank$education))
bank$default<- ifelse(bank$default == "yes", 1, 0)
bank$housing <- ifelse(bank$housing== "yes", 1, 0)
bank$loan<- ifelse(bank$loan== "yes", 1, 0)
bank$month <- as.numeric(as.factor(bank$month))
bank$contact <- as.numeric(as.factor(bank$contact))
bank$poutcome <- as.numeric(as.factor(bank$poutcome))
bank$y <- ifelse(bank$y== "yes", 1, 0)

# create normalization function
normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}
#normalize the data to get rid of outliers if present in the data set
bank <- as.data.frame(lapply(bank, normalize))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not make sense to encore the data this way.

You use Euclidean distance.

You *need* to encode the variables in a way that Euclidean distance computes a similarity that is *useful* for your problem. It strictly is *not* enough to encode stuff somehow as numbers! Garbage in, garbage out is what you get this way.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/when-clustering-doesnt-make-sense-c6ed9a89e9e6

So, the standard k-means algorithm isn't directly applicable to categorical data, for various reasons. The sample space for categorical data is discrete, and doesn't have a natural origin. A Euclidean distance function on such a space isn't really meaningful.  Basically, there is no mean for 'apple', 'orange', 'banana' or any other categorical data point.